# removing mask before saving in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a JavaScript to mask a value in my form. I'm trying to remove this mask before save it in db, but i have problems

model:

```html
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dependents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  
  # Validations #
  # Validates presence of some attributes #
  validates_presence_of :registry_number, :name, :secretary, :position, :base_salary, :rg, :cpf, :birthday, :email, :union_admission, :start_date
  validates :registry_number, numericality: {only_integer: true} 
  
  # Validates the size of some attributes #
  validates :registry_number, length: {maximum: 5}
  validates :cpf, length: {is: 11}
  validates :rg, length: {is: 9}
  validates :phone_number, length: {maximum: 11}


  :cpf.gsub(/[.\/]/, '')

end
```

error

```html
undefined method `gsub' for :cpf:Symbol

Extracted source (around line #18):
16
17
18
19
20
              


  :cpf.gsub(/[.\/]/, '')

end
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, the line `:cpf.gsub(/[.\/]/, '')` is the problem. Firstly, you're calling the method `gsub` on a symbol `:cpf`, and the method doesn't exist . Try it in irb.

Secondly, even if this wasn't the case, it wouldn't make any difference – the code is only going to be run once when the class is loaded and wouldn't be run each time you save a new `Partner`. You need to add a `before_validation` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to run your code each time you create a new object, which would look something like this:

```
class Partner
  #...
  before_validation :unmask_cpf

  #...

  private

  def unmask_cpf
    cpf = cpf.gsub(/[.\/]/, '')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

gsub is a method on strings, so you can call `.to_s` on the symbol first.

Comment: This will stop the error from happening but the `cpf` attribute won't be unmasked. All that would happen is that when the app is first booted a pointless string `cpf` would be created and a pointless `gsub` would be run on it (once) before being discarded.